# How do I test text is struck out on the page

Tags: css, cypress, strikethrough

On my ecommerce page the price of an item is reduced.

It shows the old price struck out (<s>600.00€</s>) and the new price not struck out (499.00€).

But when I query the page, I just get the text value

```js
cy.get('#normalprice span')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', '600.00€`)
```

How do I test the text is struck out? I was expecting `<s>600.00€</s>` but `cy.get('#normalprice span s')` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's using `text-decoration` to do the strikethrough.

Try getting the CSS value,

```js
cy.contains('span', '600.00€')
  .invoke('css', 'text-decoration')
  .should('contain', 'line-through')
```

The strikethrough can be also be applied on a parent, so you may need to add a `.parents()` selector

```js
cy.contains('span', '600.00€')
  .parents('div')                     // inspect to see where the CSS is applied
  .invoke('css', 'text-decoration')
  .should('contain', 'line-through')
```

Comment: If the _only_ text-decoration value is `line-through`, it could be simplified with `.should('have.css', 'text-decoration', 'line-through')`.